# Haskell: ST モナドを扱う高階関数での型エラー

Tags: haskell

Haskell の ST モナドを使った破壊的な処理で、処理の一部分を外から渡せるようにしようとしています。
たとえば下記の `printSum1` では全ての処理をハードコードしています。これを `printSum3` のように、一部の処理を引数で与えるようにしたいのですが、`printSum3` は `proc` を評価する行で型エラーになってしまいます。
`printSum2` のように、引数を取っても使わなければエラーにならないようです。
エラーを見たところでは、`ST s ()` と `ST s1 ()` という異なる型になっていて、互換性がないということのようですが…なぜそうなるのでしょうか？
`printSum3` を通す方法はありますか？
よろしくお願いします。

---

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef

add10 :: STRef s Int -> ST s ()
add10 r = modifySTRef r (+ 10)

-- add10 をハードコードする
printSum1 :: IO ()
printSum1 =
    print sum
    where
        sum :: Int
        sum = runST $ do
            r <- newSTRef 0
            modifySTRef r (+ 1)
            modifySTRef r (+ 1)
            add10 r -- ★
            readSTRef r

-- 関数を外から受け取るが、使わない
printSum2 :: (STRef s Int -> ST s ()) -> IO ()
printSum2 proc =
    print sum
    where
        sum :: Int
        sum = runST $ do
            r <- newSTRef 0
            modifySTRef r (+ 1)
            modifySTRef r (+ 1)
            add10 r -- ★
            readSTRef r

-- 外から受け取った関数を使う……これだけが型エラーになる
printSum3 :: (STRef s Int -> ST s ()) -> IO ()
printSum3 proc =
    print sum
    where
        sum :: Int
        sum = runST $ do
            r <- newSTRef 0
            modifySTRef r (+ 1)
            modifySTRef r (+ 1)
            proc r -- ★
            readSTRef r

main = do
    printSum1
    printSum2 add10
    printSum3 add10
```

---

```
exper\st.hs:43:25:
    Couldn't match type `s' with `s1'
      `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            printSum3 :: (STRef s Int -> ST s ()) -> IO ()
          at exper\st.hs:34:14
      `s1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           a type expected by the context: ST s1 Int at exper\st.hs:39:23
    Expected type: ST s1 ()
      Actual type: ST s ()
    In the return type of a call of `proc'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: proc r
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { r <- newSTRef 0;
            modifySTRef r (+ 1);
            modifySTRef r (+ 1);
            proc r;
            .... }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runST`の型は、`runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a`なので、`runST`に渡すアクションは任意の`s`に対して使用できる（`s`に対してポリモーフィックである）必要があります。

ところが、`printSum3`の型が`(STRef s Int -> ST s ()) -> IO ()`なので、`proc`は、`printSum3`全体で固定されたある特定の`s`に対してしか使用できません。このため、あらゆる`s`に対して使用できる必要のある`runST`に渡している部分（`do`ブロックの部分）の中から、特定の`s`に対してしか使えない`proc`を呼び出すことができないのです。

`proc`が任意の`s`に対して使用できることを明示すれば良いので、`RankNTypes`拡張（または、`Runk2Types`拡張）を使用して、型を以下のように指定すれば`printSum3`を書くことができます。

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
...
printSum3 :: (forall s. STRef s Int -> ST s ()) -> IO ()
```

Comment: `RankNTypes` 拡張と `forall s.` を追加することで `printSum3` を動かすことができました。
わかりやすくご説明いただき、とても腑に落ちました。ありがとうございます。